# How do I recover data after factory reset on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, factory, recovery

A friend of mine factory reset her computer on Windows 10, and lost an important document, so I'm wondering if there is a way for her to get it back, any help is useful.

I realize that a factory reset sets the computer back to it's original state of when it was first purchased, but I'm just curious if there are any free or cheap options available, besides going to a recover specialist.

Any advice would be nice - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download the free version of Piriform Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). It is something I have used before for basic file recovery, and I don't know of a simpler GUI tool for Windows. Simply follow the instructions of [this tutorial](http://www.geeksdo.com/freeware/recuva-tutorial.html), or search for a simple video tutorial on YouTube if that is insufficient.

To maximize your chances of recovery reduce the amount of writes to the drive- setting it to read-only for example. Avoiding doing anything else while you attempt to recover the files is critical, newer files may silently destroy whatever is left of the older data. If at all possible you should attempt to boot from a drive or disk that doesn't contain the erased data, but if that is not possible/not something you know how to do then you may still be able to recover the data by booting the computer normally.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm not with her - shes in another state, but I'll try to help her with this. Again thank you very much for taking the time to write this out @Emily M

Comment: Glad to help! If you have anymore questions about this post them as comments and I will try to help. If my answer solves your question please be sure to mark it as accepted. Hope she recovers her document!